# Connectng SQL Server 2012 with Java using JDBC

Tags: java, sql-server, tcp, windows-authentication, mssql-jdbc

I am using **sqljdbc4.jar** for connecting SQL Server 2008 with java application using **Windows authentication**. Everything works perfectly up to date until I tried to run the same code with SQL Server 2012.

After research, I came to know that I need to enable the **TCP/IP**. But my problem is, my applications will be distributed to users in the form of .EXE and users will install the application themselves. Also, all users will have the SQL SERVER 2012 pre-installed, my application is not supposed to install the sql server.

Now my question is, how can I connect to SQL server without enabling TCP/IP manually? I heard about shared memory protocol also, but not sure how its connection string will look like?

I am using below connection url till SQL Server 2008:

```
jdbc:sqlserver://localhost;instanceName=SQLServer12;databaseName=Test;integratedSecurity=true;SelectMethod=direct;responseBuffering=adaptive
```

Please give your suggestions so I can try it here. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is the application going to run on each users machine and use a local copy of the database?  Or are you hosting a SQL Server, with client-server architecture?

Comment: Yes, it will run on each users machine and with local copy of the database. No central server.

Comment: I'd think that would be a requirement for the team responsible for installing SQL on the machines.  Perhaps someone has a better answer though...

Comment: Yes but that is not in our hands (installation of SQL). That is out of scope :(

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the property `Network Library=dbmslpcn;` OR `Net=dbmslpcn;` to the connection string for Shared Memory. The default value is `dbmssocn` (TCP/IP).

Network Library: The network library used to establish a connection to an instance of SQL Server. The corresponding network DLL must be installed on the system to which you connect. If you do not specify a network and you use a local server (for example, "." or "(local)"), shared memory is used.

I got this from: https://www.connectionstrings.com/all-sql-server-connection-string-keywords

Comment: This seems to be a solution for the .NET platform but I need the solution for JDBC driver so please let me know what should I do with JDBC connection URL?

Comment: FYI, I'm not a MS SQL Server user, but I was curious. So I poked around the online JavaDoc for their implementation of [`javax.sql.DataSource`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/javax/sql/DataSource.html) which apparently is: [`com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource`](https://static.javadoc.io/com.microsoft.sqlserver/mssql-jdbc/7.3.1.jre12-preview/com/microsoft/sqlserver/jdbc/SQLServerDataSource.html). I do not see any setting for TCP/IP vs other connection methods such as "shared memory", but perhaps someone else might see.